# How to map a nested object in react in a rails associated models?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

after setup a simple post model with many comments what's the best way to get the comments from the post with react?

> for exemple in rails the loop would be:

```
<ul>
<%= @post.comments.each do |c| %>
     <li><%= c.title %></li> 

<% end %>
</ul>
```

in react the map is equivalent but in this case as map from a object still confuse.

```
var comments = this.state.comments.map(c => {

              return (
                 <div key={comment.id}>
                <ul >


                  <li>{comment.title}</li>


                </ul>

                  </div>

              );

            });
```

so i've tried this and as expected did not worked. so, someone has any hint on map nested arrays on react?

```
 var post = this.state.post.map(p => {

                  return (
                     <div key={comment.id}>
                    p.comments.map(c => {
                   <div key={ct.id}></div>
});

                      </div>

                  );

                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of below two options would work for you. You have to do conditional check for nested array and add return.

Below .map works with return

```
       const postItems = this.state.post && this.state.post.map(p => {
              return (
                 <div key={comment.id}>
                    if(p.comments){
                         p.comments.map(c => {
                             return <div key={ct.id}></div>
                         });
                     }
                  </div>
              );
            });
```

Or .map works without return

```
         const postItems = this.state.post &&  this.state.post.map(p => (
                 <div key={comment.id}>
                    if(p.comments){
                          p.comments.map(c => (
                               <div key={ct.id}></div>
                          ));
                    }
                  </div>
            ));
```